# Trigger ItemSend for certain outlook macros only

Tags: vba, events, outlook, mailitem

How would I modify the following code to trigger the event `myMailItem_ItemSend` only when the email is sent by `myMacro1`, but not in other cases (such as `myMacro2`)?

The event should be triggered especially for those macros using the myMailItem object.

```
Public WithEvents myMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
    Set myMailItem = Outlook.MailItem
End Sub 

Private Sub myMailItem_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
    Dim prompt As String 
    prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Send confirmation") = vbNo Then 
        Cancel = True 
    End If 
End Sub

'Should trigger the send confirmation msgbox
Private Sub myMacro1()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    Set myMailItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll
    myMailItem.Display
End Sub

'Should NOT trigger the send confirmation msgbox
Private Sub myMacro2()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    Dim oEmail As Outlook.mailItem
    Set oEmail = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll
    oEmail.Display
End Sub
```

Your kind help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the event `myMailItem_ItemSend` to be triggered only when the email is sent by `myMacro1()` and `myMacro2()`, and not every time you send an email (even manually)?

Comment: No. Only for myMacro1(), and not for myMacro2() nor the default outlook replyall function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for this:

1. Define a global variable in your module, such as `Dim TriggerMsgBox As Boolean`. By default, the variable will be false.
2. Initialize it as True in the `myMacro1()`. Only in that case, it will become `True`. Else, it will be `False`.
3. Use it in the `myMailItem_ItemSend` event: if the variable is `True` (meaning we just passed by `myMacro1()`), then you need to prompt the `MsgBox`. Else, you will just pass by. Of course, don't forget to reset the variable to `False` after the `MsgBox` is hit, else you will keep on showing it even later.

In your code it would be:

```
Public WithEvents myMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim TriggerMsgBox As Boolean '<-- NEW LINE OF CODE

Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
    Set myMailItem = Outlook.MailItem
End Sub 

Private Sub myMailItem_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
    Dim prompt As String 
    If TriggerMsgBox Then '<-- NEW LINE OF CODE
        TriggerMsgBox = False '<-- NEW LINE OF CODE
        prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 
        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Send confirmation") = vbNo Then 
            Cancel = True 
        End If
    End If '<-- NEW LINE OF CODE
End Sub

'Should trigger the send confirmation msgbox
Private Sub myMacro1()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    Set myMailItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll
    TriggerMsgBox = True '<-- NEW LINE OF CODE
    myMailItem.Display
End Sub

'Should NOT trigger the send confirmation msgbox
Private Sub myMacro2()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    Dim oEmail As Outlook.mailItem
    Set oEmail = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll
    oEmail.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there an alternative way using myMailItem? myMailItem was made public for this purpose.

Comment: @Barok that's the event to be fired when sending an email in Outlook. If you don't want to use it, you should code your own macros to emulate the catch of the event that is being fired here. It would be safer (because you would control it at 100%), but not necessarily cleaner (the event is provided by Microsoft to catch and deal with the send of an email: that's how you're using it, so I think your code is fine).

Comment: O.K. Perhaps still an alternative would be to add: if myMailItem is Nothing then Exit Sub at the first line of myMailItem_ItemSend.

Comment: @Barok you’re right, that’s for sure a check to add, but it wouldn’t solve your issue. It’s just another thing.

Comment: @Barok You cannot test for myMailItem as though it is the object from myMacro1. The item in `ByVal Item As Object` is the item triggering ItemSend for myMacro1 and myMacro2 and a manual send.

Comment: @niton thanks. So myMailItem should be corrected as an application. Something like: Public WithEvents myApp As Outlook.Application